# Which libopencv_java3.so can I delete from my apk?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have to reduce the size of my APK. I've seen that every now and then if OpenCV is around 18 MB. Assuming that my target audience are Android smartphones > 6.0 (Marshmallow) Which I can delete?

- arm64-v8a
- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- mips
- mips64
- x86
- x86_64

Comment: `armeabi`, `mips`, and `mips64` are deprecated. x86-based devices are fairly uncommon; probably mostly Chromebooks these days, so whether you want to support those is up to you. Most devices are `arm64-v8a` or `armeabi-v7a`. Note that although `arm64-v8a` devices can use `armeabi-v7a` libraries, starting in August 2019 you will be required to include 64-bit versions of any native libraries that you're providing 32-bit versions of.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the devices uses either `armeabi-v7a` or `arm64-v8a`.

Devices with `arm64-v8a` can run `.so` files of `armeabi-v7a` architecture.

But if your APK contains `.so` file of OpenCV for `armeabi-v7a` only and other `.so` files (of other libraries) for `arm64-v8a`, you cannot use the `.so` file of OpenCV of `armeabi-v7a` architecture in `arm64-v8a` CPU.

The reason for above is that the system searches for `.so` file inside the folder `arm64-v8a`. But if that folder does not exist in your APK file, it searches for the `.so` file in `armeabi-v7a` folder.

This means that you can include `.so` file of only `armeabi-v7a` architecture as long as you keep the `.so` files for `armeabi-v7a` architecture only for all libraries.